# Serving a web app from a nested folder in ASP.NET as if it was root

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack, web-deployment

I am working with an Angular 2 app that is being served with a simple ASP.NET WebApplication.

The whole code is bundled into 1 folder with webpack. Currently when I want to (re)deploy the ng app I have to delete old bundle and index.html files and paste in new ones, then include them in VS project and publish.

How would I go about serving all those files from a dist/ folder in my asp.net app without changing the autogenetared files?

I tried putting the folder, that includes index.html, there, and adding path to that index file in web.config, but then I also need to update the autogenerated paths to bundles on index.html, because by default it still looks at the root dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may set base tag in your html.

```
   <head>
    <base href="/dist/" >
   </head>
```

so all the URL will be relative to that.

And you may access your application by navigating to

```
   <root url>/dist/index.html
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That's a good idea, but if I go this route, I'll need to add that line everytime before deploying, since dev is running on a src dir.

Comment: if you are using cli or any build engine, you may configure that with production build so that you wont have to do it manually every time.

Comment: For any searchers, be sure to check the path. Mine was more deeply nested, so the files were at '/app/root/dist/root/'